# Help with two dimensional polar axis Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, wick-theorem

This is a problem that I met in real-life physics research. This question is related to Wick's theorem. The question is:

1.
    In two dimensional plane with polar axis, why do we have the following relation: 
    $\int  e^{i\bf{p}\cdot \bf{a}}/p^4  \space d^2p = C \space R^2 (\ln(R))^2 $, where $C$ is a constant, $ \bf{a}$ is a vector and $R = |\bf{a}|$.

2. Moreover, how do we calculate the following:

$\int  e^{i\bf{p}\cdot \bf{a}}/(p^4 + C_1 p^2)  $